# Is there a correct directory structure for a jQueryUI installation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

At the moment, I have jQuery and jQueryUI installed like this:

```
js/jQuery/
js/jQueryUI/
```

I'm getting an error that seems to be related to loading CSS files. Is there a 'proper' way to include jQueryUI - should it be a subfolder of jQuery, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the jQueryUI file into the same location as the jQuery file -

```
jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js
```

and it works without errors.

I don't explicitly load anything from the jQueryUI location, and I will eventually test remove the folder.

I'm surprised that this isn't documented and that nobody suggested it.

Comment: I really don't understand your post... why would it cause any kind of problems? You put your files anywhere you want to, until the paths are correct and reachable... But jQuery UI's files don't have to be in the same directory as jQuery's... 404 errors caused by unreachable images, script, stylesheets, etc. can be discovered with browsers' web developer tools (Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, Opera Dragonfly, etc.). You can download jQuery UI in a packed zip. The simplest working way is to extract it in an own folder (under your scripts' folder) and leave it alone.

Comment: The question was over a year ago however I think I was concerned about the ui looking for shared core css and/or duplicating css files unnecessarily. As I recall, there was nothing to suggest an optimal installation, nor even an indication that listing the ui before the core would cause problems!

Comment: Yes, it was over a year ago, but I accidentally found this question when looking for a jQuery UI-related topic. Could you be more specific what do you mean by "duplicating css files unnecessarily"? Where? (Every separate UI-themes have their own CSS-files.)
"listing ui before the core" -> do you mean by putting UI's path in the source before the jQuery core library's? By the way, there's a very good tutorial in the "Getting started" section: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started (and I think it was written more than a year ago :P ), where the correct order of libraries is illustrated.

Answer (score 2):

I typically just put all js files in a folder like "js" or "Scripts" and css files in a "CSS" folder.  as long as you reference them from your HTML, it doesn't matter where they are.

however, I believe jQueryUI looks for images in a subfolder of where the CSS file is.

Comment: This is correct.  I usually do a find/replace on my jqueryUI css file to point to where the image files are, because I don't like having an image folder inside my css folder.

Comment: Do the js scripts make any reference to the paths to the CSS (relative or absolute)? Or is it down to me to ensure the css files are loaded?

Comment: not that I know of.  try using Firebug in Firefox (on the "Net" tab) to see if any of your files are returning 404's

Comment: that's why I'm here (the 404), but I can't see which file it refers to.

Comment: I think it might be jQuery/themes/base/ui.base.css, but that file exists in that location. It's difficult to say with certainty because its a CMS that wraps the 404 in comfortable clothing.

Comment: The scripts do not care where your images are.  They only add and remove classes.